# Add Shortcode to ::before class

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, shortcode, css

I want to add a button (that will open an INFO popup screen with info about a certain option in a woocommerce variable product), all that can be easily created with a plugin that converts the whole thing to a shortcode, the problem is to insert it into the products page, this will run on hundreds of products so i cannot simply add it on the HTML directly.

I will attach below the CSS code that works to add an IMAGE to where i want, but im guessing we cant use the "Content" CSS to add shortcodes or so i tried..

Please advice me how can i insert a shortcode in that EXACT location (that is only one of the lines that will use the INFO button, each variable title will get a different one)

```
.label [for=pa_size-of-product]:before {
    content: url(shortcode would go here, but only images or text work with this option) !important;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It should be more helpful if you post an actual URL with place where you want to add the code.

Comment: H Twelvell, here is a link to a dummy product, basically i want to place the shortcode (which will be a button that opens a modal, created in Elementor Pro) in the place of the Facebook icon, which i placed there via CSS so you can easily see the spot i want, basically i will do the same on all the variable titles, with different shortcodes, thanks!

Comment: Forgot the link haha - http://back.frapids.pt/produto/test-01/?attribute_pa_size-of-product=s-size&attribute_pa_type-of-product=canvas&attribute_pa_style=style-02

Answer (score 0):

You can’t do what you’re trying to do.

If you want to output a shortcode you need to do it in the content or template. You can’t place one with CSS.

Comment: Hi Jacob, yes i know i cant put shortcodes via CSS (only text and image), thats why im asking how can i insert it via function.php or something else, i know some html/css, but zero at php haha :)

Also to point out, i cant do it directly on the HTML page because this will run on hundreds of products

Answer (score 0):

in functions.php

```
echo '<style>.label [for=pa_size-of-product]:before {
content: "' . do_shortcode("[your-shortcode]") .'" !important;}</style>';
```

Comment: You should always try and include an explanation in your answer so that other users can not just see a piece of code but get a better understanding of how and why things work; that way if we're all educating one another we're just building the community and adding more users that can answer questions.  :-)